# Average number of rows created per day?

Tags: mysql, statistics

Example table structure:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default               | Extra                       |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                      | char(25)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                  |                             |
| created_at              | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

*How do I find out the average number of rows added per day?*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This will return an `int` number:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct date(created_at))
from your_table
```

To get a `decimal` number use:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct date(created_at))
from your_table
```

Comment: These numbers can be misleading if you do not have changes every day. For example, if you 100 new rows added on just 3 days out of the last 6 months, you will get back an average of 33.333 which is the average for each day there were changes but not on average how often there are changes.

Comment: Yes, just pointing out that this is the average per unique date in the DB and would not be considered by a laymen as the average per day.

Comment: @Justin I have exactly this problem, any tips?

Comment: @DouglasNassifRomaJunior I am not aware of an easy query to get the avg per day when not all days have entries. I manually calculated the number of days in my date range, queried for the total of rows created in that range then divided those to get a more reasonable answer.

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT AVG(rowsPerDay) AS avgPerDay
FROM ( SELECT 
         COUNT(*) AS rowsPerDay
       FROM tbl
       GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
     ) AS a
;
```

Comment: Upvoting this, because although a little more verbose, it's easy to switch to MAX, MIN, etc to get more insight.

Comment: If there are days where no entries were added this gives you wrong results.

Comment: Neither of these will work if there are days with 0 rows, correct? I suppose if you needed every day you could just calculate the # of days since the first day and use that.

Comment: So what would be needed to avoid days where no records exist for created_at?

Answer (score 2):

> Neither of these will work if there are days with 0 rows, correct? I suppose if you needed every day you could just calculate the # of days since the first day and use that

This works in MariaDB:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF ( CURRENT_DATE() , MIN(DATE(created_at)) ) AS "Avg. rows per day" 
FROM your_table;
```